# Adding more than one instance to database

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple JSF + Hibernate + Spring + Mysql java application that I run it on Tomcat7.On JSF view page, it has only one add button,which instances can be added to database via clicking it.It runs perfectly when adding the first instance.But, when I try to add one more instance at the same session, the program fails with the following error:

```
  An Error Occurred:

org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.springhibernatejsf.model.Person
```

After googling this error, I found that it might be due to `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` instead of `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` in modal class, or using `session.persist()` instead of `session.merge()`in DAO implementation class.But, both of them didn't work for me.

Person.java:

```
package com.springhibernatejsf.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Entity bean with JPA annotations
 * 
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
@ManagedBean(name="person")
@SessionScoped
public class Person implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String country;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

PersonDAOImpl.java:

```
package com.springhibernatejsf.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.springhibernatejsf.model.Person;

@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class);

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }
    @Override
    public void addPerson(Person p){
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(p);
        session.flush();
        logger.info("Addition is successful!");
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Person> listPersons() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Person> personsList = session.createQuery("from Person").list();
        for(Person p : personsList){
        }
        return personsList;
    }
}
```

Why does this occur?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in `PersonDaoImpl` for `addPerson()`

```
public void addPerson(Person p){
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(p);
        session.flush();
        logger.info("Addition is successful!");
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

The thing is `persist()` must be used within `transaction` boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But i have the same error after adding second instance.

Comment: `persist` operation is intended for brand new transient objects and it fails if id is already assigned. In your case you probably want to call `saveOrUpdate` instead of `persist`.

Comment: i called saveOrUpdate, but nothing changed.